# When "check-all" box checked, check others

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form located on my html page with a bunch of checkboxes as options. One of the options is "check-all" and I want all the other check boxes to be checked, if unchecked, as soon as the "check-all" box is checked. My code looks something like this:

```
<form method = "post" class = "notification-options">
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "all-post" onClick = "javascript:checkALL(this
);"> All Posts <br/>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "others-post"> Other's Posts <br/>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "client-post"> Cilent's Post <br/>
<input type = "checkbox" name = "notification-option" id = "assign-post"> Task Assigned </form>
```

java script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var $check-all = document.getElementbyId("all-post");
    function checkALL($check-all){
            if ($check-all.checked == true){
                document.getElementByName("notification-option").checked = true;
            }
        }
</script>
```

nothing happens when I run my code

Comment: Why would you want checked boxes to become unchecked when someone clicks "check all?" Doesn't that defeat the purpose of "check all?"

Comment: Does your code something else you've expected? If so, what is it? What is your question?

Comment: Youre right, typo. Changed it

Comment: nothing happens when i run my code

Comment: Include that in your question. Have you checked the console for errors? What you see in the console? You should see an error message, since `$check-all` is not valid variable name (it includes illegal `-` character).

Comment: `onClick = "javascript:checkALL(this);` Where's your checkALL function? And the variable names can't contain hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some guidelines.

1. `type` attribute is not needed and can be omitted.
2. JS variable names can't contain hyphens, a typo in
   `getElementById()`
3. You're using a global variable name as an argument, in the same time
   you're passing `this` from online handler. The passed argument shadows the
   global within the function.
4. `if (checkAll.checked)` does the job
5. Typo in `getElementsByName()`, `gEBN()` returns an HTMLCollection,
   which is an array-like object. You've to iterate through the
   collection, and set `checked` to every element separately.

Fixed code:

```
<script>
    var checkAll = document.getElementById("all-post");
    function checkALL(){
        var n, checkboxes;
        if (checkAll.checked){
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("notification-option");
            for (n = 0; n < checkboxes.length; n++) {
                checkboxes[n].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can also omit the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol and the argument from online handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using jQuery:

```
$("#all-post").change(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);      
});
```

**Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4L7E/1/)**

Comment: Looks like OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: That doesn't mean they can't.

Comment: Then it's better to explain how.

Answer (score 0):

if all post check box is checked it will set check=true of others-post and client-post check boxes

```
$("input[id$=all-post]").click(function (e) {
if ($("input[id$=all-post]").is(':checked')) {
$("input[id$=others-post]").prop('checked', true);
$("input[id$=client-post]").prop('checked', true);
}
});
```

Comment: Looks like OP is not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if any of the checkboxes are not checked first.

- If so, then loop through them and check any that aren't.
- Else, loop through them and uncheck any that are checked

I have an example at http://jsbin.com/witotibe/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/AX3Uj/

```
<form method="post" id="notification-options">
    <input type="checkbox" name="notification-option" id="all-post"> All Posts<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="notification-option" id="others-post"> Other's Posts<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="notification-option" id="client-post"> Cilent's Post<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="notification-option" id="assign-post"> Task Assigned
</form>

function checkAll(ev) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementById('notification-options').querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    if (ev.target.checked === true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```